# Apache Kylin is not available locally after commadn run `docker run`

Tags: kylin

I test the apache product 'Kylin'. My machine OS is a Ubuntu Linux 18.04.

After run commands below, I am unable to get response on url `http://127.0.0.1:7070/kylin/login`. Do you have any idea what and where may the problem be at?

```sh
docker pull apachekylin/apache-kylin-standalone:4.0.0
docker run -d -m 8G -p 7070:7070 -p 8088:8088 -p 50070:50070 -p 8032:8032 -p 8042:8042 -p 2181:2181 --name kylin-4.0.0 apachekylin/apache-kylin-standalone:4.0.0
```

The logs for build and up steps (`docker logs $CONTAINER_ID`) are below:

> mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be
> insecure. mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line
> interface can be insecure. mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the
> command line interface can be insecure. 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO
> namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:
> /************************************************************
> STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode STARTUP_MSG:   user = root STARTUP_MSG:
> host = 89b6bbb8441f/172.17.0.2 STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
> STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.8.5 STARTUP_MSG:   classpath =
> /home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/etc/hadoop:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.5.2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core4-4.0.1-incubating.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-client-2.7.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-framework-2.7.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/json-smart-1.3.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/nimbus-jose-jwt-4.41.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.4.4.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.54.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.8.5-tests.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/okio-1.4.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/htrace-core4-4.0.1-incubating.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/okhttp-2.4.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/hadoop-hdfs-client-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-native-client-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-native-client-2.8.5-tests.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.8.5-tests.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-client-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-client-2.8.5-tests.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/java-util-1.9.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-math-2.2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6-tests.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/curator-client-2.7.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/json-io-2.5.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/fst-2.50.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/curator-test-2.7.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/spark-2.4.7-yarn-shuffle.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-sharedcachemanager-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-timeline-pluginstorage-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.8.5.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.8.5-tests.jar:/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar
> STARTUP_MSG:   build =
> https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r
> 0b8464d75227fcee2c6e7f2410377b3d53d3d5f8; compiled by 'jdu' on
> 2018-09-10T03:32Z STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_141
> ************************************************************/ 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for
> [TERM, HUP, INT] 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO namenode.NameNode:
> createNameNode [-format] 23/10/15 13:32:12 WARN common.Util: Path
> /data/hadoop/dfs/name should be specified as a URI in configuration
> files. Please update hdfs configuration. 23/10/15 13:32:12 WARN
> common.Util: Path /data/hadoop/dfs/name should be specified as a URI
> in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration. Formatting
> using clusterid: CID-427a376b-5314-4ac5-8029-7f1a7ec3219f 23/10/15
> 13:32:12 INFO namenode.FSEditLog: Edit logging is async:true 23/10/15
> 13:32:12 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: KeyProvider: null 23/10/15
> 13:32:12 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsLock is fair: true 23/10/15
> 13:32:12 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Detailed lock hold time metrics
> enabled: false 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager:
> dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO
> blockmanagement.DatanodeManager:
> dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check=true 23/10/15
> 13:32:12 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager:
> dfs.namenode.startup.delay.block.deletion.sec is set to
> 000:00:00:00.000 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager:
> The block deletion will start around 2023 Oct 15 13:32:12 23/10/15
> 13:32:12 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap 23/10/15
> 13:32:12 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO
> util.GSet: 2.0% max memory 889 MB = 17.8 MB 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO
> util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries 23/10/15 13:32:12
> INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
> 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager:
> defaultReplication         = 1 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO
> blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
> 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication
> = 1 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO
> blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
> 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager:
> encryptDataTransfer        = false 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO
> blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxNumBlocksToLog          = 1000
> 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             =
> root (auth:SIMPLE) 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem:
> supergroup          = supergroup 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO
> namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = true 23/10/15 13:32:12
> INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false 23/10/15 13:32:12 INFO
> namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO
> util.GSet: Computing capacity for map INodeMap 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO
> util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO util.GSet:
> 1.0% max memory 889 MB = 8.9 MB 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^20 = 1048576 entries 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO
> namenode.FSDirectory: ACLs enabled? false 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO
> namenode.FSDirectory: XAttrs enabled? true 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO
> namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occurring more than 10 times
> 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map
> cachedBlocks 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
> 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO util.GSet: 0.25% max memory 889 MB = 2.2 MB
> 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^18 = 262144
> entries 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem:
> dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033 23/10/15
> 13:32:13 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem:
> dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO
> namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
> 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf:
> dfs.namenode.top.window.num.buckets = 10 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO
> metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.num.users = 10
> 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf:
> dfs.namenode.top.windows.minutes = 1,5,25 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO
> namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache on namenode is enabled 23/10/15
> 13:32:13 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache will use 0.03 of
> total heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis 23/10/15
> 13:32:13 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map NameNodeRetryCache
> 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit 23/10/15
> 13:32:13 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 889 MB =
> 273.1 KB 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new
> BlockPoolId: BP-1958866213-172.17.0.2-1697376733028 23/10/15 13:32:13
> INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /data/hadoop/dfs/name has been
> successfully formatted. 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO
> namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf: Saving image file
> /data/hadoop/dfs/name/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 using
> no compression 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf:
> Image file
> /data/hadoop/dfs/name/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 of size
> 321 bytes saved in 0 seconds. 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO
> namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid
>
> > = 0 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0 23/10/15 13:32:13 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
> > /************************************************************
> > SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at 89b6bbb8441f/172.17.0.2
> > ************************************************************/ chown: missing operand after '/home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/logs' Try 'chown
> > --help' for more information. starting namenode, logging to /home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/logs/hadoop--namenode-89b6bbb8441f.out
> > starting datanode, logging to
> > /home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/logs/hadoop--datanode-89b6bbb8441f.out
> > starting resourcemanager, logging to
> > /home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/logs/yarn--resourcemanager-89b6bbb8441f.out
> > starting nodemanager, logging to
> > /home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/logs/yarn--nodemanager-89b6bbb8441f.out
> > starting historyserver, logging to
> > /home/admin/hadoop-2.8.5/logs/mapred--historyserver-89b6bbb8441f.out
> > JMX enabled by default Using config:
> > /home/admin/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg Starting zookeeper ...
> > STARTED Checking HDFS's service... HDFS's service started...

I thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I presume you've been following the steps described here https://kylin.apache.org/docs/install/kylin_docker.html

Once the container is started, you need to connect to it, launch a script, and wait for it to finish before accessing the web UI :

```sh
docker exec -it kylin-4.0.0 bash
# once you are connected to the container
$KYLIN_HOME/bin/sample.sh
```